# MySQL - Pass input parameter into Cursor query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

Is it possible to pass input parameter into Cursor SELECT statement WHERE clause?

For some reason I think it isn't working.

I'm trying to pass `_TAG` and `_ITEM_NAME`  into where clause.

```
DECLARE cursor_test cursor for SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE  key_ LIKE "sometext_@_TAG_sometext_@_ITEM_NAME" AND STATUS = '0';
```

Here is the the Stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getSomething(IN _HOSTNAME VARCHAR(20), _TAG VARCHAR(20), _ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
declare FINISHED BOOL default false;

DECLARE cursor_test cursor for SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = @_HOSTID AND key_ LIKE "sometext_@_TAG_sometext_@_ITEM_NAME" AND STATUS = '0';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER for not found set FINISHED := true;

SET @HOSTNAME = _HOSTNAME;

PREPARE STMT1 FROM

"SELECT hostid INTO @_HOSTID FROM hosts  WHERE NAME = ?";

EXECUTE STMT1 USING @HOSTNAME;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT1;

open cursor_test;
   SET @TOTAL_VALUE := 0;
   loop_itemid: loop
        fetch cursor_test into _ITEMID;
        SELECT _ITEMID;
        if FINISHED then
            leave loop_itemid;
        end if;
        SET @TOTAL_VALUE := @TOTAL_VALUE + (SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = _ITEMID ORDER BY clock DESC LIMIT 1);

   end loop loop_itemid;
   SELECT @TOTAL_VALUE;
close cursor_test;

END //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [akina's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina). Using CONCAT in where condition worked.

```
WHERE key_ LIKE CONCAT('sometext_', _TAG, '_sometext_', _ITEM_NAME)
```